# Lazy loading - UITableview visible cells not showing the images

Tags: iphone, uitableview, lazy-loading

I have implemented lazy loading of images in the uitableview using apple’s lazy loading example. Everything works fine except for one part. Initially when I start the app the table's visible cells don’t load any images. But as I scroll the table the images are getting loaded for the remaining cells and are retained. But the initial visible cells remain blank.

Anyone had similar problem?

Could anyone please guide me solving this issue?

```
static NSString *EditCellIdentifier = @"EditCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EditCellIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:EditCellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
 }
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}   
    if ([listItems count]>0)       
    {    
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    ListItem * item = [listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *imageFrame = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,60,60)];
    [imageFrame setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"]];
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
      otherPath=indexPath;
        if (!item.appIcon)
        {
            if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
            {
                NSLog(@"Initial Values %@",item.imageURL); 
                if([item.imageURL length]==0){
                    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[categoriesImages objectAtIndex:self.configfId - 1]];
                }  
                else
                    [self startIconDownload:item forIndexPath:indexPath];
           }
       }
        else
        {
            imageView.image = item.appIcon;
        }
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];       
    NSString * titleStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@",item.rank,item.title];        
    NSLog(@"titleStr %@",titleStr);    
    CGSize size = [titleStr sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:11] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(12, 100) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];       
    if (size.height > 50 ) {            
        size = CGSizeMake(size.width,50.0 );            
    }        
    NSInteger height = 14;        
    if(item.title.length > 30){            
        height = 25;            
    }           
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];        
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageFrame];
}    
return cell;              
}
```

Comment: Please add your code of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to your question.

Comment: what is the source of your images, are these local or coming from web ?

Comment: Almost certainly you are only loading the images when you get a redraw, but as the first comment says, without seeing your cellForRowAtIndexPath it would just be a guess

Comment: I have added my code.... The source is web

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to help you in your code But i would like to suggest you use `SDWebImage` for lazy loading. You will found it here https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/. And there is a great tutorial regarding this with titled **"How To Use It"**.